# Grand total in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Relation    hhc101  hhc166  hhc201  total
1           1435        18       1  1455
2            430         2       0   434
3           1121         0       0  1124
Grand total 2986        20       1
```

I am novice in SQL. I am trying to get this table. Could please help me get this table.
thanks
my original table is

```
GrpNum  MemberNum   Relation
HHC101   397            3
HHC101   663            1
HHC101   707            2
HHC101   903            3
HHC166  1206            3
hhc166  1326            2
HHC166  1800            1
HHC201  1839            3
HHC201  1951            1
HHC101  2098            1
HHC101  2146            3
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, is something like below.  Sorry I'm on a home computer without any tools to try this out.  Look up PIVOT in the MSDN for more information

```
SELECT Relation, [HHC101] AS HHC101, [HHC166] AS HHC166, [HHC101] AS HHC101
FROM 
(SELECT Relation, GrpNum, MemberNum
FROM your_table_name_here ) p
PIVOT
(
SUM (MemberNum)
FOR Relation IN
( [HHC101], [HHC166], [HHC101] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.Relation;
```